# Flutter - Manipulate position of shadow casting lights

Tags: flutter

### Question

Is there a way to manipulate the position of the lights flutter uses to compute the shadow of PhysicalModel widgets?

### Background

I would like to avoid the animation connected to a device orientation change. Instead, I am locking the app to one preferred orientation and detect orientation changes using the accelerometer. Then, only the necessary widgets are rotated as necessary.

Now, I have the little aesthetic problem that Material shadows are cast in a way that is connected to the current device orientation: They always point downwards.

[Shadows correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ5yP.jpg)

However, if the orientation is locked to one side and I rotate the screen by 180°, my widgets rotate as wanted, but the shadows are now pointing upwards instead of downwards.

[Shadows incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2VTX.jpg)

Now, I would like to adjust the position of the lights to change the shadow for all PhysicalModel widgets instead of drawing a custom shadow for every single widget.

Comment: Why not use a **Container** instead, set the shadow via the **BoxDecoration** property so you can manipulate the shadow direction using the BoxShadow's offset property, even via an animation)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the suggestion. However, I would then have to do this for every single Material Widget in my app which would be a bit tedious. I also don't know whether the elevation then still has an effect on the appearance of the shadow. This is for example visible when a button gets pressed.

Comment: But I believe you could create a common widget that encapsulates this configuration, and just inject the widget inside that you want this to be applied, thus reusing this.

Comment: After having dug down the source code searching for the place where the shadows are computed, I kind of come to the conclusion that this is not intended. As far as I could see are the shadows handled inside of Skia. That is where I stopped searching 

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Maybe this is the way to go. I will have to find out how to write something like this.

Comment: No doubt - I love how Flutter uses Skia for painting everything, and the flexibility that it gives you, but I think there's just a few cases where you can't go any further. This might be one of them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the position of the light for computing the shadows is hardcoded. The crucial line of code can be found [here](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/dbe4cc89ba335057d8492d9a2583cac8ffd9ce12/display_list/display_list_canvas_dispatcher.cc#L277).

```
SkShadowUtils::DrawShadow(canvas, path, SkPoint3::Make(0, 0, dpr * elevation),
                        SkPoint3::Make(0, -1, 1),
                        kLightRadius / kLightHeight, ambientColor,
                        spotColor, flags);
```

The implementation of the function called can be found [here](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/9867574f7198a1ff7b68af6bffd8197e6c11bdc0/src/utils/SkShadowUtils.cpp#L607).

Comment: I think you may add that 1 line of code (the first link) for simplicity.